# Codimension of generic fiber of smooth morphism

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

Let $f: X \to Y$ a smooth, dominant map between two irreducible smooth schemes $X$ and $Y$. let $\eta$ be the generic point of $Y$.

Question: why the codimension of generic fiber $X_{\eta}= f^{-1}(\eta)$ in $X$ coinsides with the dimension of $Y$?

Recall: $codim(X_{\eta},X)= codim(\overline{X_{\eta}},X)$, since in general $X_{\eta}$ is not closed. by definition of codimension, $codim(\overline{X_{\eta}},X)= \max_i(X_i,X)$ where the $X_i$ are irreducible components of $\overline{X_{\eta}}$. therefore, assume that the generic fiber $X_{\eta}$ is irreducible. Can someone please help me how to proceed?

Comment: The dimension of the generic fibre of $f$ is the relative dimension  $\dim X - \dim Y$ of $f$. So, its codimension equals $\dim X - (\dim X - \dim Y) = \dim Y$.

Comment: about your second point I pretty not sure. firstly, one consequence of smoothness is that indeed every fiber (especially the generic) of arbitrary point $y \in Y$ has dimension $\dim(X_y)= rank_y(\Omega_{X/Y})= \dim(X)-\dim(Y)$, that's fine. what I not understand is why this imply that the codimension of the fiber is $\dim(X)-\dim(X_y)$? by definition codimension of a closed irreducible set $A \subset X$ is the maximal chain lenght $l$ of irreducible sets $A =X_0 \subset X_1 \subset ... \subset X_l =X$. why in our case for $A:= X_{\eta}$ the $l$ coinsides with $\dim(X)-\dim(X_{\eta})$?

Comment: Ok, I see. The “codimension” of the generic fiber is zero, as its  closure equals X. It’s a matter of definitions. The dimension of the generic fiber is the relative dimension. It’s maybe best not to talk about its codimension

Comment: can we say something interesting about codimension of a fiber of a closed point $s \in Y$, ie $X_s$, or more "precisely" almost every closed fiber? again, by smoothness, $\dim(X_s)= \dim(X)-\dim(Y)$ as above. what about $codim(X_s,X)$? do you know about a possibility to attack this question? my background was to say something about the codimenion of **general** fiber.

Comment: so firstly I tried the strategy to find out the codimension of generic fiber as what was the starting point of this thread (is $=0$ as you explained above) and then by maybe something like upper semicontinuity argument to extend the statement to all fibers over an open set of $Y$. but this would lead me to absurd statement that there exist an open set $U \subset Y$, such that for every $y \in U$ the fiber $X_y$ has codimension $0$ in $X$. intuitively this seems to be absurd...

Comment: If you're going to change your question that much, you need to edit this post significantly or ask a new question. I would also like to point out that this post is a version of the [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/) - in the future, if you add the context of how you got to this problem (and follow other advice in the link), answerers can more easily help you with your underlying issue as well as the difficulties faced in your solution.

Comment: ok, that's a good idea